# Помогите решить задачку на с++

Tags: c++

Ну, как сказать "помогите", я могу написать код лишь до функции main(). И вообще, лабораторку дали, а лекций с таким материалом вообще не было, хз, как это делать. Задача звучит так
"По указанию пользователя вычислить количество и сумму положительных элементов
или Или сумму отрицательных нечентных элементов массива m(15)".
Кто-нибудь знает, как это делать?
Я разобрался, как посчитать количество и сумму положительных элементов. Но не понимаю, как посчитать сумму отрицательных непарных, и как это сделать за указанием пользователя

```
   #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[5],sum = 0, count = 0;
    cout << "Enter mas: \n";

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    cin >> a[i];

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    if(a[i]>0){sum += a[i]; count++;}

    cout << "Sum = " << sum << "  Kol-vo = " << count;

    cin.get();
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Здесь задачи за вас решать не будут. Пытайтесь решить сами, показывайте, что именно не получается и мы вам поможем

Comment: Ну вы же посчитали положительные? Вот точно так же и отрицательные. Проверка нечетности - равен нулю или нет остаток от деления на 2, а вычисляется он для числа `a` как `a%2`.

Answer (score 1):

Кол-во отрицательных эл-ов можно посчитать следующим образом:

```
for (int i = 0; i<15; i+=2)
  if (m[i]<0)
    sum +=m [i];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    if ((a[i] < 0) && (a[i]%2)) 
        sum += a[i];
```